# Display conditional image in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which displays some data.
Now I want to add an image-column.

I tried it like this :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TegelCheckerModel>()
            .Name("Grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.IsTegelZichtbaar).ClientTemplate("#= getImage(data)#");
            })
            .AutoBind(true)
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Filterable()
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax() //Or .Server()
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetTegels", "TegelChecker")
            .Data("getAlvNummerAndVoorWie"))
            )
        )
```

and then in js I do the following :

```
function getImage(data) {
            var html;

            if (data.IsTegelZichtbaar) {
                html = "<img src='~/Images/valid.jpg' />";
            }
            else{
                html = "<img src='~/Images/notvalid.jpg' />";
            }
            return html;
        }
```

The images exist but they are not displayed.
What am I missing? What am I not seeing?

Comment: did you try adding alerts() in your getImage function to make sure you're hitting the right spots?  make sure you set the height and width also]

Comment: Images get html encoded

Comment: @JamieD77: I am getting in the getImage-function, so that is not the problem

Comment: @JamieD77 : setting the size didn't help either.

Comment: You may try this instead of calling a function: `columns.Bound(p => p.IsTegelZichtbaar).ClientTemplate("#if(IsTegelZichtbaar){# <img src='~/Images/valid.jpg' /> #}else{# <img src='~/Images/notvalid.jpg' /> #}#");`

Comment: @Werner: i tried it, but it doesn't work either. My page-source now shows this : "template":"#if(IsTegelZichtbaar){# \u003cimg src=\u0027~/Images/valid.jpg\u0027 /\u003e #}else{# \u003cimg src=\u0027~/Images/notvalid.jpg\u0027 /\u003e #}#"

Comment: you try setting the url using `src='@Url.Content("~/Images/valid.jpg")'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with uploading the image.
SO that is why it was not displaying.
Stupid me for not checking that.